# PHP Read file and extract only the require key

Tags: php, explode

I have a file which contain data like this -

```
keysuccess
line1
line2
keyerror
line3
line4
line5
keyfail
line6
line7
```

From here I would like to extract the line3, line4, and line5 which is the group of keyerror

something like -

```
$array = explode("keyerror", file_get_contents($file));
```

Comment: see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5775452/php-read-specific-line-from-file

Comment: @Tim thanks for your reply but my file contain is dynamic. Somethime the keysuccess contain only line 1 and keyerror contain 5 line. So I want to get all the line in an array starting from keyerror to next word which start by "key"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way i can think with that specific file structure is by using [file()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file.php), assuming the keys starts from `keyX`

```
$rows = file($file,FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
$found = FALSE;
$lines = array();
foreach($rows as $key => $row) {
   if ($found && substr($row,0,3)=="key") {
      break;
   }
   if ($found) {
      $lines[] = $row;
   }
   if ($row === "keyerror") {
      $found = TRUE;
   }
}

print_r($lines);
```