# PHP read a large file line by line code modifies to read selected lines

Tags: php

I have large text file that contain 800 K lines size 60 MB.I tried this code

```
$fileData = function() {
    $file = fopen('800K.txt','r');
    if (!$file)
        die('file does not exist or cannot be opened');
    while (($line = fgets($file)) !== false) {
        yield $line;
    }
    fclose($file);
};

foreach ($fileData() as $line) {
   echo $line.'<br>';
}
```

It really works : ).but con is it reads all line 800 K lines :( ....... it is possible convert into for loop , so it will be easy to selected line like

```
for ($i=1; $i<=10000; $i++){ 
$line=trim($lines[$i]); 
}



ANSWER :
$i=0;  //// start number
foreach ($fileData() as $line) {
   if($i==100) break;  ///// end number
   echo $line.'<br>';
   $i++; 
}
```

Comment: `be easy to selected line like`.  Not sure what you're asking.  Could you clear  up your question.

Answer (score -1):

Edit:

This post has a few tests where they do this with larger files...

https://stackoverflow.com/a/31235307/2405805

```
$file = '../data/800k.txt';
$lines = file($file);
$rangeStart = 200000;
$rangeEnd = 300000;
$selection = array_slice($lines,$rangeStart,$rangeEnd);
echo json_encode($selection);
```

Or:

```
$file = '../data/800k.txt';
$rangeStart = 200000;
$rangeLength = 100000;
foreach (new LimitIterator($file, $rangeStart, $rangeLength) as $line) {
    array_push($lines,$line);
}
echo json_encode($lines);
```

Note, I'm not 100% with these methods if the item starts at 0 or 1, so it may be (200000, 300000) or (199999, 299999);

Comment: If you have a gigabyte of free memory for the script...

Comment: Yeah, sorry, misread the question. I'll update this in a bit with a better answer.

Comment: Updated with a better answer...

Comment: @Devon  i have 16 GB RAM for server

Comment: @digitalhigh how it possible to get lines from 200K to 300K

Comment: If you're using the first example:

 `$selected = array_slice($lines, 200000, 300000);`

Of for the second example:

`$i = 199999;
$spl->seek($i);
$lines = [];
while ($i <=299999) {
    $i++;
    $spl->next();
    array_push($lines, $spl->current();
}
// $lines will then contain all elements from 200000 to 300000.  
`
Note, I'm not sure if you need to start with item 199999 or 200000 with the $spl item.

Comment: @meethayaam - Updated the example to provide a range selection...

Comment: A more idiomatic way, when using SPL, would be to use a [LimitIterator](http://php.net/limititerator). E.g. given an SplFileObject in `$file`, you could read 100 lines from offset 12345 with a loop like: `foreach (new LimitIterator($file, 12345, 100) as $line) { ... }`

Comment: @salathe - That's pretty...

Comment: @digitalhigh too much difficult solution .it is not possible to modifies my question code